# Finding clickon Element using Selenium. (JAVA)

Tags: selenium

I spend hours already trying to find the way to find the Element using Selenium WebDriver. I assume I need to use driver.findElement(By.xpath("")), but I am not quite sure how.

I somehow need to find and click on "clickon" element. The problem is that part of that element is changing (see screenshot) I need to pick up from the file and putted into the xpath.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: What is the div contained in? Put a bit more of structure of the html and there can be a relative path that can be formed from something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

We have been rigorously searching for automated functional testing solutions recently, and we began with Selenium. The entire reason we decided to search for other solutions was that our application also has dynamic IDs with no other obvious XPath mechanism to identify them. Selenium is unable to identify these elements on the page without some additional knowledge, just as you would be unable to identify these elements on the page if you didn't already know what they are.

If you are controlling the DOM creation, consider adding a unique ID or class to this element.

We recently came across eggPlant from testPlant, and it is an interesting approach to functional testing. It's essentially image based. Other viable solutions are Ranorex or HP's QTP or SmartBear's TestComplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath. If the div class is constant, you can use something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("list-row field-item")).click();
```

To view the xpath, you can install firefox plugin called 'xpath checker' found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) and right click on the dom element and click 'View Xpath' option to get the xpath of the element and then you can use that xpath in your code.

Or you can even use regex in the xpath which is suitable for the similar problems. Xpath with regex is really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to click the div that has the `on click` attribute that contains certain text that doesn't change, ignoring the part that does.  In that case, use an xpath like this:

```bash
//div[contains(@onclick, '/challenge/index/rfp_id/')]
```

This will select the first div with an `onclick` attribute with a value containing `/challenge/index/rfp_id`.